# Python list comprehension/ ternary operator: If condition, then append incremented value, else append non-incremented value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following loop in Python that I want to turn into a list comprehension:

```
index = 0
    for i in range(number):
        vec[i] = index
        if condition:
            index += 1
```

This should make vec look something like `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6].` However, I am struggling to create a list comprehension for this.

My attempts look like this:

```
y=[]
index = 0
[index+=1 and y.append(index) if condition else y.append(index) for _ in range(number)]
```

In iPython this just doesn't even execute.

Comment: You shouldnt use list comprehensions for side effects **to begin with** they are for expressing declarative mapping/filtering operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The walrus operator can do the job for you ... but I heartily agree with @juanpa: **don't**.
This is hard to read and hard to debug.

```
>>> index = 0
>>> [ index := (index+1 if i%3 == 1 else index) for i in range(10) ]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

I've used `i%3 == 1` as your "condition".

Comment: Fascinating, I've never heard of the walrus operator. I'll have to check it out. Are there uses for it which are not difficult to read or debug?

Comment: Remember the first rule of posting: research, research, research.  Don't ask *me* whether there are such uses -- look it up!  Yes, there are.  The operator is new in Python 3.8, I think, and it has much better uses.  The name comes from turning the operator sideways, like a :-) smiley.